# How do I add old Windows to boot up menu?

Tags: windows-10, boot

I've installed a second Windows 10 on an another partition. The old Windows doesn't appear in the boot up list, so how can I add the old Windows, and how do I change the priority to the old Windows?

Comment: What version of "old windows"?

Comment: both are Windows 10

Comment: Type "msconfig' in search box, under boot tab to see if your old Windows 10 exits.

Comment: It doesn't show there, but I think it exists (the OS files are still there). Isn't there a way to edit boot options (i.e., add an entry for the old Windows 10 to the boot list)?